# How to create a javascript object within an object?

Tags: javascript, object

For example:

```
function userObject(start_value) {  
    this.name = start_value;
    this.address = start_value;
    this.cars = function() {
        this.value = start_value;
        this.count = start_value;
    };
}
```

Obviously the above dosent work but would appreciate the direction to take to have cars available as:
    userObject.cars.value = 100000;

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that functions (and thus "object definitions") can be nested (there is absolutely no requirement that this is nested, but having it nested here allows a closure over `start_value`):

```
function userObject(start_value) {  
    this.name = start_value;
    this.address = start_value;
    function subObject () {
        this.value = start_value;
        this.count = start_value;
    }
    this.cars = new subObject();
}
```

However, I would likely opt for this (just create a new "plain" Object):

```
function userObject(start_value) {  
    this.name = start_value;
    this.address = start_value;
    this.cars = {
        value: start_value,
        count: start_value
    };
}
```

Happy coding.

Comment: this.cars = {
        value: start_value,
        count: start_value
    };
did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

so simple anser is to use the object syntax

```
function userObject(start_value) {  
 this.name = start_value;
 this.address = start_value;
 this.cars = {
  value: start_value,
  count: start_value
 };
}
```